# convert a date sql

Tags: sql, date

Hello I got a date like it :

```
id    date 
1     01MAY2021
```

I want do a request who returns me all line when date is 01may2021.

I dit it :

```
 
SELECT * where date="2021-05-01";
```

thanks

Comment: where date='01MAY2021' ?

Comment: I tried it but it didn'(t work

Comment: Can you share the structure of the table you are doing the query on?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query based on which database oracle or Sql server.

use your appropriate table name instead  of rtable_name

oracle

```
select * from table_name where to_char(date, 'yyyy/mm/dd') = '2021/05/01'
```

Sql Server

```
select * from table_name where FORMAT(date , 'yyyy/mm/dd')  = '2021/05/01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date could be stored as string, which is why your match does not work. If so, you can find information on how to convert that to a date [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-functions-for-converting-string-to-date/).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from xyz where date=convert(date,'01MAY2021')

No need to use the format function. Just cast the string to Date. It will automatically format the expected date.